# Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Tags: php, wordpress

I am receiving some variables from a form:

```
$start = $_POST['startDate'];
$start = explode(",", $start);
$end = $_POST['endDate'];
$end = explode(",", $end);
```

Then If I check the arrayss:

```
echo '<pre>' . var_export($start, true) . '</pre>';
echo '<pre>' . var_export($end, true) . '</pre>';
```

I get:

```
array (
  0 => '1984',
)
array (
  0 => '2017',
)
```

If I do:

```
<h2><?php echo $start; ?>, <?php echo $end; ?></h2>
```

I get blank results.

But I do the following it's fine:

```
<h2><?php foreach($start as $st) { echo $st; } ?>, <?php foreach($end as $en) { echo $en; } ?></h2>
```

However, I am running a query afterwards:

```
query_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'cache_results' => false,
        'no_found_rows' => true,
        'update_post_meta_cache' => false, 
        'update_post_term_cache' => false, 
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'usp-custom-14',
                'value'   => array($start, $end),
                'compare' => 'IN',
                'type'    => 'NUMERIC'

            )
        )
    )
);
```

And the results are a warning:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string,
>   array given...

And the whole lists of all the articles.

I need to only find the articles which have in a `custom field` the values I get from the `form variable`

I tried to change `'type' => 'NUMERIC'` to `'type' => 'CHAR'` and I only get the `warning` but no results.

Comment: The error is extremely clear, you can't pass an array to the function, it *has* to be a string. Confirm what you are passing to it is actually a string.

Comment: @Script47 you mean i should change` 'value'   => array($start, $end),` to `'value'   => $start, $end,` ?

Comment: Try and that and find out, I've not actually looked through your code properly.

Comment: BTW, you can miss out the escaping aspect by using prepared statements.

Comment: @Script47 look like it is working indeed, could you paste that as an answer?

Comment: Instead of using mysqli_real_escape_string look into prepared statements with bound parameters. This is the preferred method for putting user data into queries. It is more efficient when executing the same query multiple times with different data and it helps eliminate human error in case you forget to escape one single variable in a list of 15 that you thought was ok to use.

Comment: @Mike well that comes from wordpress, not going to modify the core

Comment: @rob.m Quick 20 second search brought me to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/. Does that work for you? I have no idea if behind the scenes these are real prepared statements or emulated (like PDO can do), but it might be a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only two values to compare like in this case you could set up multiple meta queries:

```
query_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'cache_results' => false,
        'no_found_rows' => true,
        'update_post_meta_cache' => false, 
        'update_post_term_cache' => false, 
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'       => 'usp-custom-14',
                'value'     => $start[0],
                'compare'   => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'usp-custom-14',
                'value'     => $end[0],
                'compare'   => 'LIKE',
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: mmm that actually is a better way, I'd need to use AND not OR tho. I'll accept it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To mark this as answered, you need to pass a string not an array to said function:

Change,

```
'value'   => array($start, $end),
```

To

```
'value'   => $start . $end,
```

As mentioned in my comment, consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead, it is more safe and saves you from having to escape values.

Comment: on a sidenote, how would I keet the variables if I refresh the page? Not sure how to use SESSION if that is what I'd ever need..

Comment: Can you provide an example with prepared statements please?

Comment: '*Can you provide an example with prepared statements please?*' - The link I've provided has many examples on how to use them. Might sound harsh but reading the manual is much better than me telling you for two reasons, the manual is the originating source so it will be more in-depth and it makes you learn and become self-reliant.

Comment: '*how would I keet the variables if I refresh the page?*' - Many ways, cookies, sessions, db or a file.

Comment: if I do `$start . $end,` I get zero results, if I do `$start, $end,` I only get results about `$start`

Comment: I had to remove the explode and then do `array($start,$end),` as wordpress accepts an array there